# Can't compile aapmsamp.tex in revtex4-2

Tags: revtex

I am writing a manuscript to be submitted in Medical Physics Journal which uses `revtex4-2` package. I already have a package `med_phys_latex_template_NEW` which is enough for preprint preparation but I have to check the estimated number of pages in final journal printed page and hence intended to try `revtex4-2`.

After downloading it from https://journals.aps.org/revtex I tried to run the `aapmsample.tex` file using `latex aapmsample.tex` inside the directory `./revtex4-2-tds/doc/latex/revtex/sample/aapm` after placing required files `revtex4-2.cls`, `revtex4-2.sty`, ... in that directory. But I am getting this error message in the terminal:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./aapmsamp.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 5 language(s) loaded.
(./revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c (https://journals.aps.org/re
vtex/ for documentation)
ltxutil[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
ltxfront[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
ltxgrid[2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
Class revtex4-2 Warning: No Society specified, using default society aps.
(./aps4-2.rtx)
Class revtex4-2 Warning: No journal specified, using default pra.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (./revsymb4-2.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
\setup@hook ...elsep \let \@listi \@listI \@listi 
                                                  \set@page@grid \providecom...
l.7590 \setup@hook

?
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the output of running `tex` on the unmodified `aapmsamp.tex`: it shouldn't give the warnings your log includes. Furthermore, you TeX distribution seems rather old (TeXLive2015). Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917).